# Looping through inner array in a filter function in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter the array here but the result seem to be empty. How do I loop through inner array in a filter function?

Below is the snippet

```js
const carIds = ['100', '101'];
const carsList = [{
  name: 'BMW',
  id: '100'
}, {
  name: 'Jeep',
  id: '101'
}, {
  name: 'Audi',
  id: '103'
}];
const result = carsList.filter((val) => val.id === carIds.map((val) => val))
console.log('result', result)
```

Expected output should be

```
[{
  name: 'BMW',
  id: '100'
}, {
  name: 'Jeep',
  id: '101'
}]
```

Could anyone please advise?

Comment: `map()` returns an array. How can `val.id` be equal to an array?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do with the `.map()` method, but you're not using it right. `.map()` applies a transformation function to each element of the array, then returns a new array of the result. See [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for help with the correct usage.

In your case, you can just use the [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check if the array includes the value. Like this:

```js
const carIds = ['100', '101'];
const carsList = [{
  name: 'BMW',
  id: '100'
}, {
  name: 'Jeep',
  id: '101'
}, {
  name: 'Audi',
  id: '103'
}];
const result = carsList.filter(val => carIds.includes(val.id))
console.log('result', result)
```

Note that in this case, it is faster to use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), as it can check for membership in `O(1)` time rather than the `O(n)` that an array offers. Expand the snippet below for an example:

```js
const carIds = new Set(['100', '101']);
const carsList = [{
  name: 'BMW',
  id: '100'
}, {
  name: 'Jeep',
  id: '101'
}, {
  name: 'Audi',
  id: '103'
}];
const result = carsList.filter(val => carIds.has(val.id))
console.log('result', result)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to return the cars who's ID's are included in the carIds array?

If so you want to use the `.includes()` method instead of `.map()`.

```
const result = carsList.filter((val) => carIds.includes(val.id))
```